# becomeFirstResponder does not work in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

When calling textView `becomeFirstResponder` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns false, why?

But from other method i.e. from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it works.

Is it in connection that I am using iOS 8 introduced `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` row height approach?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check the documentation it says that the view have to be in the view hierarchy. I think in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method the text view is not yet attached to the hierarchy but when the cell is returned.

> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the
>   first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if it
>   is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it
>   returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.

Comment: interesting when setting cell height manually it works calling from cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @János Sure. Height is a property that has meaning for a view whether it's part of the view hierarchy or not. However, a view can't be first responder unless it is part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: works means becomefirstresponder works, when height is set manually

Answer (score 0):

Try calling becomeFirstResponder in a custom method of your table view cell like layoutSubviews because at that point the text view will have been added to the view hierarchy. If you call it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method the text view has not been added to the view hierarchy yet and it does not work.

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews{
    // Initialization code

    if ([self.textView becomeFirstResponder]) {

        NSLog(@"yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the cell certain to be part of the view hierarchy when awakeFromNib is called? I thought that awakeFromNib was called after outlets and actions were connected, but before the view was inserted into it's superview. (I'm not sure however.)

Comment: You are right!!!. It cannot be a part of hierarchy at the time the awakeFromNib is called. I will edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

hijack viewDidAppear for the purposes like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: whatever, inSection: 0mostlikely)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath( indexPath) as? YourTableViewCellClass {
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

viewDidLayoutSubviews is more expensive cause its called gazillion times
whilst viewDidAppear is called only once