# Swift isFirstResponder true but cursor not set

Tags: ios, swift, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

I have a ViewController that has a custom tableViewCell (of course in a tableView) with few form fields (4 UITextFields and 1 UITextView). I am making some UI updates for validation like for each error textField, the border color turns red.

Alongside changing the border to red, I also need to set the focus to the first error field (am using `becomeFirstResponder()`). This is what I have at the moment inside the `cellForRowAt` method.

```
var errorTextFieldArray = [UITextField]()
for myTextField in [(cell as! ContactEmailCell).firstNameTextField, (cell as! ContactEmailCell).nameTextField, (cell as! ContactEmailCell).countryCodeTextField, (cell as! ContactEmailCell).teleNumberTextField, (cell as! ContactEmailCell).emailTextField, (cell as! ContactEmailCell).subjectTextField] as! [UITextField] {

    switch myTextField.text?.isEmpty {
    case true?:
        errorTextFieldArray.append(myTextField)
        self.showRedBorder(forTextField: myTextField)
        self.allFieldsRequiredAlert()

    case false?:
        self.removeRedBorder(forTextField: myTextField)

    case .none:
        break
    }
}

if (errorTextFieldArray.count > 0) {
    print("errorTextFieldArray count \(errorTextFieldArray.count)")
    errorTextFieldArray[0].becomeFirstResponder()
    print("is first responder? \(errorTextFieldArray[0].isFirstResponder)")
}
```

Everything works well, including `errorTextFieldArray[0].becomeFirstResponder()` inside the `**if**` statement, but I don't see the cursor being placed in the textField.

When I do the `.becomeFirstResponder()` for any textField at the beginning of my `cellForRowAt`, then the cursor is set to that textField and the Keyboard pops-up. Could someone please help me understand why it is not working as expected from inside the if statement?

Comment: I had same problem and it turned out that I didn't set delegate for the textField I want to focus (`textField.delegate = self`)

Comment: I have the delegate set already. And, it works when I do the .becomeFirstResponder() for any textField at the beginning of my cellForRowAt

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526673/becomefirstresponder-does-not-work-in-cellforrowatindexpath